# Short sci fi story - A doctor (probably) and a prisoner in Mayan (probably) times have visions of each other's lives

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's a story that has a plotline similar to Philip K Dick's TV series *Electric Dreams*. Each of the characters views the other's life as a dream/hallucination.

- A doctor in the present time hallucinates and finds himself bound to a rock in probably Mayan times  where he is about to be killed.
- The prisoner in Mayan times dreams himself in the doctor's present and is fascinated/confused by modern technology like cars, lights, etc.

In the end, it is revealed that it was the Mayan prisoner who was dreaming as it is him who was killed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like **"The Night Face Up" by Julio Cortazar.** I found it by doing a web search for "*sci fi short story aztec each dreaming about the other*" (since I'm pretty sure it was the Aztecs and not the Mayans who were famous for human sacrifices) and found [this page](http://www.shortstoryguide.com/short-stories-about-imagination/):

> A man on a motorcycle has an accident. After he’s given an anesthetic at the hospital, he dreams he’s a Motecan Indian fleeing from Aztec warriors centuries ago in Mexico.

[You can read the story in full online.](https://www.colorado.edu/studentgroups/shortfiction/NightFaceUp.pdf)

Here's the man in the modern-day hospital (not a doctor, but a victim of a motorcycle accident), dreaming about being pursued by Aztecs in search of humans to sacrifice:

> They carried him to the radiography room, and twenty minutes later, with the already-damp sheet placed
>   over his chest like a black tombstone, he moved to the operating room.  Someone dressed in white, tall and
>   thin, approached him and examined the radiography results.  Feminine hands accommodated his head, and
>   he perceived that they were moving him from one stretcher to another.  The man in white approached him
>   once more, smiling, with something that glinted in his right hand.  He patted his cheek and gave a signal to
>   someone standing behind.
>
> It was a curious dream because it was full of smells and he never dreamed smells.  First the smell of a
>   swamp,  since at the right of the road lay a marsh,  quagmires from which no one ever returned.  But the
>   smell stopped,  and in its place came a dark and complex fragrance like the night,  through which he was
>   fleeing the Aztecs.  And it was so natural, he had to flee the Aztecs who were on a hunt for men, and his
>   only chance was to hide himself in the densest part of the jungle, taking care not to separate himself from
>   the narrow road that only they, the Motecas, knew.

And here's the ending of the story, where the man being sacrificed by the Aztecs realises that this is the true reality and the future with strange technology is the dream:

> With one last hope he parted his eyelids, groaning to
>   wake up.  For a second he thought he had achieved it, because once again he was immobile in his bed, safe
>   from the swinging with his head propped up.  But it smelled of death, and when he opened his eyes he saw
>   the bloody figure of the high priest that came toward him with a stone knife in his hand.  He was able to shut his eyelids once more, but now he know that he would not wake, that he was awake, that the marvelous
>   dream had been the other, absurd like all dreams; a dream in which he had ridden the strange avenues of
>   an astonishing city, with red and green lights that burned with neither flame nor smoke, with an enormous
>   metal insect that buzzed beneath his legs.  In the infinite lie of that dream they had also lifted him from the
>   floor, someone had also cut him with a knife in his hand, with him lying face up, face up with his eyes shut
>   in the midst of the fires.

Comment: The Mayans, sadly, were not the gentle astronomer priests we used to think them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_sacrifice_in_Maya_culture